# m.ky.onActivityCreated OOM

Tags: android, oom

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 8308486796 byte allocation with 4194304 free bytes and 479MB until OOM
       at android.util.ArrayMap.allocArrays(ArrayMap.java:203)
       at android.util.ArrayMap.ensureCapacity(ArrayMap.java:319)
       at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel(BaseBundle.java:219)
       at android.os.BaseBundle.getString(BaseBundle.java:918)
       at m.ky.onActivityCreated(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@240812005@24.08.12 (020406-0):44)
       at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.AppMeasurementDynamiteService.onActivityCreated(com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-sdk@@21.2.0:29)
       at m.cm.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@240812005@24.08.12 (020406-0):131)
       at m.s.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@240812005@24.08.12 (020406-0):21)
       at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:385)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzbm.zzc(com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base@@21.2.0:2)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzca.onActivityCreated(com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base@@21.2.0:5)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzdx.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-sdk-api@@21.2.0:8)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzdu.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-sdk-api@@21.2.0:2)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Almost happens in android 5.   Is this causes by gms??

[image]

70% is android 5

Comment: OOM is almost never caused by 1 thing.  It's total memory used.  You need to get a heap dump and analyze for leaks.  Or just drop support for Android 5, it's almost a decade old at this point.